# Turning off OS popup windows

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, xorg, raspberry-pi-desktop, lightdm

I'm currently working on a RPi 3B+ with RaspberryOS (NOT the lite version), programming a Python GUI for a life-size game. I'm trying to change how the OS behaves. I do not have experience doing that.

My GUI works but it needs to stay in focus and that's where I have problems.

Players will have to plug in a USB key to the RPi. For now, when they do, a "new media plugged-in" popup comes up. That's a problem for what I'm doing.

So : How to turn off pop-ups and notifications ? (The USB key still needs to be detected)

Alternatively : Is booting in console mode and starting my gui in a single X window a better way to avoid the problem ? (that seems very complicated for my skillset, but maybe that's the correct path ?)

Edit : Found it ! Thanks for pointing out that this feature is part of the file manager, it can actually be disabled in the options of the file manager, I was simply looking in the wrong place with the OS.

Answer (score 0):

The automount "feature" is part of file manager.

Personally I find it annoying (partly because it mounts in media).
If it is something you do regularly you can make a fstab entry.

I do not believe you can automatically mount without popup although you may be able to write a dbus rule to mount.